# compser -v doesn't show version and composer-playground command not not found on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, npm-install, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I ran all the installations 
npm install -g composer-cli ,
npm install -g composer-rest-server
npm install -g generator-hypeldger-composer
npm install -g yo
npm install -g composer-playground 
.

These commands have executed without any errors and I was able to view them at **~/.npm-global/lib/node_modules$** but I run composer --version it is not showing the version Composer version @package_branch_alias_version@ (1.0.0-beta2) 2016-03-27 16:00:34, and composer-playground: command not found.

Please do suggest if I need to setup any path manually or there is something to fix.

Answer (score -1):

I would run the curl command to install composer on Ubuntu

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer -o composer-setup.php
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is a different Composer.  The original question is looking for Hyperledger Composer.

Comment: I have resolved the issue........ It was unable to set the path........ Thank you